# Using patched Powerline fonts for vim-airline

Tags: vim, ubuntu-14.04, vim-plugin, vim-powerline, powerline

I've cloned vim-airline with Pathogen. Next I cloned patched Powerline fonts into `/usr/local/share/fonts` on my Ubuntu 14.04, and did `fc-cache -vf /usr/local/share/fonts`. I then added `set guifont=Ubuntu\ Mono\ for\ Powerline\ 11` as well as `set laststatus=2` and `let g:airline_powerline_fonts=1` in my .gvimrc.

I'm having two problems: I'm not getting the fancy Powerline symbols, and the spacing on my fonts has been increased.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

It's supposed to be

```
set guifont=Ubuntu\ Mono\ derivative\ Powerline\ 11
```

For problems with fonts in future:

- select font via `set guifont=*`
- get fontname `set guifont`
- don't forget to escape spaces

Comment: This addresses the problem I was having with the spaces on my fonts, but I'm still not getting the fancy Powerline symbols.

Comment: It may be problem with those fonts you cloned. I have used [this](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) repo and just run `instal.sh`.

Comment: I removed my `/usr/local/share/fonts/fonts` directory and cloned from the repo you mentioned above, then I ran `./install.sh`. Unfortunately, I'm still not getting the fancy Powerline symbols.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas, but did you run `fc-cache` on `/usr/local/share/fonts`? And does `set guifont` print correct font?

Comment: @pacholik I had the same problem and your steps solved for me, I was missing the `fc-cache ` and setting the guifont. Thanks.